# What point is the torque on a loop in a magnetic field taken about?

Tags: electromagnetism, rotational-dynamics, torque

I know that the torque on a loop kept in uniform magnetic field is given by

$$\vec{\tau}=\vec{M}\times\vec{B}$$

where $\vec{M}$ is magnetic moment. Now, can I take this torque about any point in space, or are there any restrictions?

Comment: Please don't use MathJax to format mere text, it is a waste of resources. Also, if you have reason to think this might be closed as duplicate, *link* to the question people might think it is a duplicate of and explain why it is not, instead of just saying it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: I am new to stack exchange and I am not familiar with many of the features like formatting text using MathJax or how to link other answers. That is why I have just told that this is not duplicate. I have searched the web and PSE but found no question like this.